# Javascript: how can I tell if a <span> is broken over 2 lines?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I display a bubble help for some short span elements. The bubbles are centered below that span and look great as long as the span isn't broken over two lines.

Looks good:

```
tell <span>irregular: told, told</span>
```

Looks bad:

```
tell <span>irregular: told,
told</span>
```

It looks bad, because the bubble isn't centered under the span anymore. Is there some way using JavaScript or jQuery to tell, if that span is broken over two lines?

Comment: If span spans more than one line, its height is greater than height of a single line of the same font. Maybe you'll be able to check it.

Comment: Why would a single newline influence the way the span displays?

Comment: I think he's saying if the span looks that way, not if that's the actual html.

Comment: @9000: Just duplicating the font information isn't quite enough, the length of the span also depends on `word-spacing`, `letter-spacing`, and possibly a couple other things; that's why I wrapped the first word in a span rather than building a span in a hidden `<div>` or something similar. Adding an extra span in the same context/block seemed safer and less fragile.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

9000's comment is correct. The trick is having access to a `<span>` that you know will be rendered on a single line. You can do that by wrapping the first word of your block in a span with a specific `id`, you could also use the last word or some other single word; there are cases where a single word will cross lines but the first word should be safe.

Once you have something that is only on one line you can compare its height to the height of the `<span>` that will get the tooltip. If the `<span>` that is getting the tooltip is taller than the single-line `<span>` then it has wrapped to multiple lines.

Try this jsfiddle:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/JbMhZ/1/

Adjust the size of the right panes until the red text wraps but the green text doesn't. Then hit **Run** in the toolbar at the top and it should say this at the bottom of the *Result* pane:

```
#has-break spans more than one line
#no-break spans only one line
```

I'm not exactly proud of this hack but it should work.

I'm left wondering if a better positioning algorithm for your tooltip would be a better idea. Maybe pull the mouse coordinates out of the hover event and use that to position the tooltip rather than positioning it based on the `<span>`.

Comment: Good idea, you can also give all `span` elements same `line-height` then compare each span height to that value instead of creating "dummy" span. :)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: Except that `line-height` and rendered height aren't the same thing, they're related but not in any nice clean way. This updated fiddle should demonstrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/JbMhZ/2/. My first thought was to compute the expected height of a single line `<span>` but I gave up on that, Javascript just doesn't offer clean access to all the metrics we need to compute the pixel size of a piece of text. Anything to do with rendered text pixel size or line wrapping is a mess of nonsense in CSS/HTML/JavaScript.

Comment: @mu interesting, I thought giving `line-height` will force that height on every line no matter what font is used. :/

Comment: The `line-height` is, more or less, about how far down the page the rendering cursor goes when a line break (explicit or implicit) is inserted in a block; inline elements don't know about `line-height` as they delegate most of the "line" issues to their containing block. If you set `#text { line-height: 8px }` in the fiddle you'll see what I'm talking about. Yet another seemingly simple problem that is full of subtle issues that are quick to anger :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the nicer way to do this would be with [`white-space: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space) in CSS:

CSS:

```
span.bubble {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

HTML:

```
tell <span class="bubble">irregular: told, told</span>
```

Comment: and if you want that span to be part of your text?

Comment: @Radagaisus The span is part of the text, but line breaks won't happen within the span. Read the linked docs.

Comment: The cure is worse than the disease. It'll look ugly enough with shorter bits of text that just look like awkward line breaks, but what about bits of text longer than one line? They'll just overflow out of the container.

Answer (score 0):

With or without a line break you can just calculate using `.css()` in jQuery where exactly on the screen is that span located and then position the tooltip accordingly. Or you can use a [jQuery plugin](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=jquery+tooltip+plugin) to do all this for you.

Answer (score -4):

Not quite sure what levels of help you're looking for, but `\n` is the identifier for linebreaks in JS

Comment: Question isn't asking about line breaks in the HTML (although the example is misleading), but rather about inline elements wrapping to a new line.