# Perform jquery if text has certain amount of lines

Tags: jquery

Hello I have kind of a crazy question but is it possible to perform jquery if text has certain amount of lines?

Basically the logic I am looking for is:

If the text in a DOM element is on 2 lines, then perform this jQuery.

So the psuedo code will look like

```
<p class="element">some text some text some text</p>

if jQuery(".element") is on two lines {
    //perform some code
}
```

I was just wondering if this is possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: how can I tell if a <span> is broken over 2 lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575787/javascript-how-can-i-tell-if-a-span-is-broken-over-2-lines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this issue before and ended up checking if the element (e.g. a p tag) went past a certain height:

```
if ($('p.element').height() > 18) { // 18 being the font-size
  // Run some code
}
```

**NOTE:** Of course, you will need to know the font-size before adding the condtion. This may not work if using em font-size measurements as, if i'm correct, these are dynamic.

Please see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atvu498p/2/)